# Produce a gridded map in R where each grid cell shows the share of points of a certain category

Tags: r

So I have a big dataset of points across Europe with each point representing a certain category. What I would like to do is make a grid of a certain size, ie. 1kmx1km and plot the share of each category in each grid cell.

My dataset looks something like this but with many more observations:

```
df <- data.frame(category = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                 X = c(60,61,60,56,58,61,57,61,60),
                 Y = c( 20,21,20,19,19,21,20,20,20))
```

And here is a simple illustration of the type of maps I would like, with grid cells, where the color of the grid cell indicates the share of that category in that cell.

[image]
What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Do you know anything about working with spatial data in R using the `sf` and `terra` packages? We really need to know where we're starting from, because the short answer is probably something like "use `rasterize(pts, r, fun=sum)` from the `terra` package"